# Unable to see mirrored traffic with wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark

I am trying to monitor the network traffic coming/going into my network. I have a switch setup between the modem and the router where I have the port going to the router mirrored to a port connected to a NIC on my server. When I try to use wireshark to monitor the port I see nothing really other than `router advertisement` `solicitation` etc. no real IP traffic. The switch I am using is the `TP-Link 5 Port Gigabit Switch (TL-SG105E)`. The NIC should automatically set in promisicious mode when I launch wireshark from what I understand.

What am I forgetting?

Note: the NIC has to use a self-assigned IP address(169...) cause there's no DHCP on its leg of the network though the switch can do DHCP, I am pretty sure that doesn't matter.

EDIT----
Something is happening with TP-Link's software that looks like is preventing me from changing the settings for port mirroring:

https://youtu.be/6uH41CAwgbE

What do you think is going on?